# Only default controller is working while hosting the website

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, web-hosting

I created a website that has been working prperly on my local host but when i host it its just showing me the default controller and when i am trying to load the other controllers then showing error **The resource requested could not be found on this server!**

My config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.livebookit/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

My Routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome/about';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['index']= 'frontend/WebController/home';
$route['about']= 'Welcome/about';
$route['services']= 'frontend/WebController/services';
$route['contact']= 'frontend/WebController/contact';
$route['contact_form']= 'frontend/WebController/contact_form';
$route['search']= 'frontend/WebController/search';
```

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

please help me to get out of this problem

I tried alot have change my baseurl many time make it empty , and even also changed the index.php in config
o empty,to index.php? and changed the uri_protocol wih manythings but nothing helped me andeven rechecked the names of my controller as the firstletter must be capital and i was using wamp its working on wamp but not while hosted

Comment: In the above, I see your missing in base_url the .com or .net or ?? - Also, looks like you deployed on a linux server. Capital letters make a difference as "WebController" is not the same as "Webcontroller" - I see you checked this, but also check inside the controller and how you named it there. The generic error is because the system is in production mode, you can check the logs to give you more details